# Apache directory listing: Permission denied

Tags: apache-2.4, directory-listing

So, I want to achieve something which should be easy: I want my Apache webserver to deliver its automatically generated directory listing since it is about statics HTML and PDF files.

However, I always receive an HTTP 403 response.

The error log says:

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/my-website/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

And this is the output of `ls -l /var/www/html/my-website`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root root 4096 Jul  5 10:06 /var/www/html/my-website
```

And from `getfacl /var/www/html/my-website`:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/html/my-website
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

This is, stripped down to the relevant aspects, the virtual host configuration section:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
    ServerName my-website.local
    AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    Alias / /var/www/html/my-website/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-website/
    <Directory /var/www/html/my-website/>
        AllowOverride none
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, since `o+rx` is set, I expect it to be readable. What else am I missing?

Comment: would it be possible to paste the relevant section of Apache config? The error you shared complains about a missing "DirectoryIndex" section (which is a file that Apache looks by default when it traverse a particular directory)

Answer (score 1):

So, I can answer the question on my own, now. I post this answer here in case someone else stumbles over the same problem before spending 4 hours with it.

If the virtual configuration is correct, then probably a global configuration is not.

In this case, there was another configuration file named `welcome.conf` in place, obviously a default file from CentOS, which prevented the directory index from being delivered. The intention of this configuration file is to load the welcome page instead of listing a directory. The context of this configuration file is global.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have

```
Options -Indexes
```

Somewhere related to my-website definition.

Change it to

```
Options +Indexes
```

And reload/restart/refresh.

Otherwise check for Selinux contexts with:

```
# ls -la --context /var/www/html/my-website
# chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/my-website/
```

Comment: I edited my question to contain the config.